# What is the way to extract check box values from a document using python in Google DocumentAI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwToM.jpg)

I want to extract the value of this checkbox (document) by getting response from **Google DocumentAI** using python code.

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai
import re

def get_text(doc_element: dict, document: dict):
 
    response = ""
     for segment in doc_element.text_anchor.text_segments:
        start_index = (
            int(segment.start_index)
            if segment in doc_element.text_anchor.text_segments
            else 0
        )
        end_index = int(segment.end_index)
        response += document.text[start_index:end_index]
    return response

def getIndexes(dfObj, value):
    
    listOfPos = list()
    result = dfObj.isin([value])
    seriesObj = result.any()
    columnNames = list(seriesObj[seriesObj == True].index)
    
    for col in columnNames:
        rows = list(result[col][result[col] == True].index)
        for row in rows:
            listOfPos.append(row)
   
    return listOfPos

def online_process(
    project_id: str,
    location: str,
    processor_id: str,
    file_path: str,
    mime_type: str,
) -> documentai.Document:
   
    opts = {"api_endpoint": f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com"}


    documentai_client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    resource_name = documentai_client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)

   
    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

        
        raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(
            content=image_content, mime_type=mime_type
        )

      
        request = documentai.ProcessRequest(
            name=resource_name, raw_document=raw_document
        )

        result = documentai_client.process_document(request=request)

        return result.document
```

The code which I'm using to extract values is above but while using that I'm getting empty string as values for check box.

Answer (score 0):

For processing forms, you can get the best results by using the [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser)

Checkboxes are treated as Key-Value Pairs in the output. (Note: Checkboxes inside tables are currently not supported)

Here is the documentation for how to handle the Document object output for the Form Parser
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables

When I tried converting the JPG you uploaded to PDF, then trying it with the form parser, I got the following results:

[image]

It was able to extract the unchecked boxes, but it looks like the current model isn't able to parse this style of checkbox when it's fully filled in.